# Cuda always get out of memory when training data with colabs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

So i have 2DCNN models to classify image, there are just 2 class, i have 300 images each class.
here is my nn module class

```
class Flatten(Module):

    def forward(self, input):

        return input.view(input.size(0), -1)

class ActionNet(Module):

    def __init__(self, num_class=4):

        super(ActionNet, self).__init__()



        self.cnn_layer = Sequential(

            #conv1

            Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1, bias=False),

            BatchNorm2d(32),

            PReLU(num_parameters=32),

            MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3),

            #conv2

            Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1, bias=False),

            BatchNorm2d(64),

            PReLU(num_parameters=64),

            MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3),

            #flatten

            Flatten(),

            Linear(576, 128),

            BatchNorm1d(128),

            ReLU(inplace=True),

            Dropout(0.5),

            Linear(128, num_class)

        )



    def forward(self, x):

        x = self.cnn_layer(x)

        return x
```

i split training and test 80%:20%, for more detail here is my training code: https://pastebin.com/uzBFTrDc , when i try to train with colab there is an error:

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.90 GiB total capacity; 15.20 GiB already allocated; 1.88 MiB free; 15.20 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

i use google colab because i don't have powerfull GPU and implement batch that i dont know whether it's correct or not, the training data is just 400 image with size 32x32,i think colabs is powerful enough to train my data.

Comment: What is your batch size? Have you tried lowering it?

Comment: i try manual batching and use 64, 32, even 4 the error still appears

Comment: does test data have to use batch too?

Comment: Yes. You are not using any batch size for the test?

Comment: no im not using batch for validation, how to pass it to train method because i use loop for training batch

Comment: i don't know i just saw it in tutorial, what is the differences?

Comment: how to pass it to train method because i use loop for training batch - pass the same way you pass the train data as argument to the train function

Comment: you tagged `tensorflow` as well, do you both import `tensorflow` as well as `pytorch`? because tensorflow allocates all GPU memory at the start of the program. Maybe pytorch also wants to allocate some but can't because tensorflow is hogging al the memory :s

Comment: Please remove appropriately one of `tensorflow` or `pytorch` tags, depending on what you actually use.